# Change the way AWK read file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

anyone could help me to achieve this ,normally AWK read file

```
a b c
```

as

```
$1:a
$2:b
$3:c
```

how to read this file

```
a
b
c
```

as

```
$1:a
$2:b
$3:c
```

Many thanks for help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can unset the Record Separator and change the Input Field Separator to the newline character:

```
$ awk -F'\n' -vRS='' '{print $1,$2,$3}' file
a b c
```

Comment: Thanks for that ,could you help me to to solve the left question

Comment: No problem. I think you should ask your second question separately, as there are ways of solving the problem that are unrelated to the original question. If you think there's a way to do it using this answer, you should try it yourself and show your efforts in a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ cat file
a
b
c

d

$ awk -v RS='^$' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "$"i"="$i; print "----"}' file
$1=a
$2=b
$3=c
$4=d
----
```

Note the difference wrt `d` with Tom's solution of setting RS to the NULL string:

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS='' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "$"i"="$i; print "----"}' file
$1=a
$2=b
$3=c
----
$1=d
----
```

Think about how you want your script to behave if there are blank lines in the file.