# How to use Awk in this situation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

how to change this file

```
335
339
666665
666668
```

to this result

```
335
336
337
338
339
666665
666666
666667
666668
```

explain : between two numbers with the same long, it will push the missed number to make numeric ascending order .Many Thanks

Comment: Will it always be blocks of two numbers of same length? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What about records between `339` and `666665`?

Comment: @anubhava "between two numbers with the same long"

Comment: i just want to push with the two same-long numbers.No need to care about others

Comment: Oh `same long` is probably meant `same length`

Comment: @YOU is your desired output fine? I see you want `666669` to be printed, while the file contains `666668`.

Comment: ok .that was a mistake ,let i edit .

Comment: It's disappointing to see that since asking the [same question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25709368/2088135) (since edited) you have made no attempt to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this does what you want.

```
awk 'alen==length($1) {for (i=a;i<=$1;i++) print i}; {a=$1; alen=length(a); if (a==(i-1)) {a++}}'
```

When `alen` (the length of a) is the same as the length of the current line loop between `a` and `$1` printing out all missing values.

Then set `a` to the new `$1`, `alen` to the length of `a`, and when we dealt with a missing range (when `a` is the same as `i - 1`) increment a so we don't duplicate that number (this handles cases of sequential lines like `335`, `339`, `350` without duplicating `339`).

With credit to @fedorqui for the basic idea.

Edit: I believe this fixes the problem I noted in the comments (which I think is what @JohnB was indicating as well):

```
awk '{f=0; if (alen==length($1)) {for (i=a;i<=$1;i++) print i} else {f=1}} {a=$1; alen=length(a)} a==(i-1){a++} f{print; a++}'
```

I feel like there should be a simpler way to do that but I don't see it at the moment.

Edit again: The input file I ended up testing with:

```
335
339
340
345
3412
34125
666665
666668
```

Comment: +1 Could add `1` to print non matching lines without the increment.  e.g. line of `123` followed by `1234`.

Comment: @JohnB I'm not sure I follow that suggestion exactly but it does bring up an issue. If there is a single line of a given length this answer will not print it at all.

Comment: @JohnB I thought you might have meant that but couldn't be sure. The problem with that is that it double prints the start and end of ranges.

Answer (score 3):

The first approach is this:

```
$ awk 'NR%2 {a=$1; next} $1>a {for (i=a;i<=$1;i++) print i}' file
335
336
337
338
339
666665
666666
666667
666668
```

It can be improved as much as info and effort you put in your question :)

#### Explanation

- `NR%2 {a=$1; next}` as `NR` stands for `n`umber of `r`ecord (number of line in this case), `NR%2` is 1 if NR is not multiple of 2. So this stores the value of the line in the variable `a` in the odd lines. Then, `next` stops processing current line.
- `$1>a {for (i=a;i<=$1;i++) print i}` in the other cases (even lines), if the value is bigger than the one that was stored, it loops from that value up to the current one, printing all the values in between.

Comment: @YOU added some information. Try to add some of your attempts the next time!

Comment: It needs some further tuning actually. If last record is `666669` after `666668` then it is not printed.

Comment: @anubhava true! Just added a comment in the question to clarify. Eagle eye :)

Comment: What I meant is this. Add `340` just below `339` in input file and run this script again.

Comment: @anubhava I was writing an update but now I see Etan Reisner just posted a great solution for this case. I assumed the input was a pair of values, hence the `NR%2`. But his approach is more general and would be preferred for a more general solution. +1 for him!

Comment: @fedorqui i dont know why your solution not solve the job if the file is longer

Comment: @YOU my solution works fine if you have blocks of two numbers, one at each line - as you requested. But it does not consider the length of them, it just assumes data is exactly like `A / B / C /D` and prints from A to B and from C to D (if A<B and C<D in every case).

Comment: Thanks ,i was thought your solution for same length ,but Solution of @Etan Reisner could help me ,anyway thanks much .