# Collapse sequential numbers to ranges in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, compression

I am trying to collapse sequential numbers to ranges in bash. For example, if my input file is

```
1
2
3
4
15
16
17
18
22
23
45
46
47
```

I want the output as:

```
1 4
15 18
22 23
45 47
```

How can I do this with awk or sed in a single line command?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25727477/258523) of mine might be helpful in giving you the general sort of idea.

Comment: oops! thanks for catching that. I edited my question! Sorry, @EtanReisner, I couldn't figure out how to print 2 different lines in a single line from that link.

Comment: How do you want to treat a _singular_ number `1 2 3 4 8 20 21 22 23 24`?

Comment: @gboffi the data always occurs as pairs, so, 8 wouldn't exist (in the above string).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{first=$1;last=$1;next} $1 == last+1 {last=$1;next} {print first,last;first=$1;last=first} END{print first,last}' file
1 4
15 18
22 23
45 47
```

Explanation

- `NR==1{first=$1;last=$1;next}`

  On the first line, initialize the variables `first` and `last` and skip to next line.
- `$1 == last+1 {last=$1;next}`

  If this line continues in the sequence from the last, update `last` and jump to the next line.
- `print first,last;first=$1;last=first`

  If we get here, we have a break in the sequence.  Print out the range for the last sequence and reinitialize the variables for a new sequence.
- `END{print first,last}`

  After we get to the end of the file, print the final sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot @John1024 ! I really appreciate your effort explaining it to me!

Comment: With regard to my comment to the OP question (i.e., a single 8 among the sequences), your code prints `8 8` and from my personal POV it's the right thing to do.