# piping commands of awk and sed is too slow! any ideas on how to make it work faster?

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to convert a file containing a column with scaffold numbers and another one with corresponding individual sites into a bed file which lists sites in ranges. For example, this file (**$indiv.txt**):

```
SCAFF      SITE
1           1
1           2
1           3
1           4
1           5 
3           1
3           2
3           34
3           35
3           36
```

should be converted into **$indiv.bed**:

```
SCAFF      SITE-START   SITE-END
1              1            5
3              1            2
3              34           36
```

Currently, I am using the following code but it is super slow so I wanted to ask if anybody could come up with a quicker way??

### COMMAND:

```
for scaff in $(awk '{print $1}' $indiv.txt | uniq)
do
      awk -v I=$scaff '$1 == I { print $2 }' $indiv.txt | awk 'NR==1{first=$1;last=$1;next} $1 == last+1 {last=$1;next} {print first,last;first=$1;last=first} END{print first,last}' | sed "s/^/$scaff\t/" >> $indiv.bed
done
```

### DESCRIPTION:

```
awk '{print $1}' $indiv.txt | uniq  #outputs a list with the unique scaffold numbers 

awk -v I=$scaff '$1 == I { print $2 }' $indiv.txt #extracts the values from column 2 if the value in the first column equals the variable $scaff

awk 'NR==1{first=$1;last=$1;next} $1 == last+1 {last=$1;next} {print first,last;first=$1;last=first} END{print first,last}' #converts the list of sequential numbers into ranges as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809668/collapse-sequential-numbers-to-ranges-in-bash

sed "s/^/$scaff\t/" >> $indiv.bed #adds a column with the respective scaffold number and then outputs the file into $indiv.bed
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/38627863/874188 can help you straighten out this pretzel logic slightly.

Comment: To all the "put on hold"-ers: The question doesn't say "this isn't working", but "it's slow". Are such questions really off-topic here? The code runs well and shows the expected output.

Comment: Also, here's a solution in Perl that should be faster: `tail -n+2 indiv.txt | sort -u -nk1,1 -nk2,2 | perl -ane 'END {print " $F[1]"} next if $p[0] == $F[0] && $F[1] == $p[1] + 1; print " $p[1]\n@F"; } continue { @p = @F;'`

Comment: solution using single `awk` call; assumes data is in file`scaff.txt`; applies set of tests/actions as each line is read: `awk 'function print_scaff () { if ( scaff != -9 ) { printf "%-10s %-15s %-10s\n",scaff,start,end } } $1 == "SCAFF"   { printf "%-10s %-15s %-10s\n","SCAFF","SITE-START","SITE-END"; scaff=-9; next } $1 != scaff { print_scaff() ; scaff=$1; start=$2; end=$2; next } $2 != (end+1) { print_scaff(); start=$2; end=$2 ; next } $2 == (end+1) { end=$2 ; next }  { print_scaff() } END { print_scaff() }' scaff.txt`  NOTE: had to strip out comments to fit into this comment block

Comment: @mernster key objectives: 1) eliminate the (possibly large volume of) repetitive scans of the data file and 2) eliminate the (possibly large volume of) sub-processes invoked by the various pipes

Comment: @mernster: the single `awk` solution also assumes the data is already sorted (as displayed by your example); if this is an invalid assumption then you'll need to pre-sort the data (see @choroba's `perl` solution for the pre-sort step)

Comment: @choroba amazing!! it worked in just a few hours! you make my day :) thank's a lot!

Comment: @markp thanks a lot for your advice on how to increase the speed super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Calling several programs for each line of the input must be slow. It's usually better to find a way how to process all the lines in one call.

I'd reach for Perl:

```
tail -n+2 indiv.txt \
| sort -u -nk1,1 -nk2,2 \
| perl -ane 'END {print " $F[1]"}
             next if $p[0] == $F[0] && $F[1] == $p[1] + 1;
             print " $p[1]\n@F";
             } continue { @p = @F;' > indiv.bed
```

The first two lines sort the input so that the groups are always adjacent (might be unnecessary if your input is already sorted that way); Perl than reads the lines,`-a` splits each line into the `@F` array, the `@p` array is used to keep the **p**revious line: if the current line has the same first element and the second element is greater by 1, we go to the `continue` section which just stores the current line into `@p`. Otherwise, we print the last element of the previous section and the first line of the current one. The `END` block is responsible for printing the last element of the last section.

The output is different from yours for sections that have only a single member.